# Cannot use instance member 'movies1' within property initializer, property initializers run before 'self' is available

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am working on a an expandable table view and got some issues.

This is working fine for testing:

```
var sections = [
    ExpandTVSection(genre: "genre1", movies: ["movie1A", "movie1B","movie1C"], expanded: false),
    ExpandTVSection(genre: "genre2", movies: ["movie2A", "movie2B","movie2C"], expanded: false),
    ExpandTVSection(genre: "genre3", movies: ["movie3A", "movie3B","movie3C"], expanded: false)
]
```

I get my data from Firebase so I tried go set the first movie names

```
var movies1 = [String]()
var movies2 = [String]()
var movies3 = [String]()

func fetchMovies(){
    var datref: DatabaseReference!
    datref = Database.database().reference()
    datref.child("movies1").child("names").observe(
        .childAdded,
        with: {
            (snapshot) in         
                if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{
                    let movie = MoviesInfo(dictionary: dictionary)
                    movie.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)
                    self.movies1.append(movie.Name!)
                }
            },
        withCancel: nil)
}

// !! program breaks here due to movies1 !!

var sections = [
    ExpandTVSection(genre: "genre1", movies: movies1, expanded: false),
    ExpandTVSection(genre: "genre2", movies: ["movie2A", "movie2B","movie2C"], expanded: false),
    ExpandTVSection(genre: "genre3", movies: ["movie3A", "movie3B","movie3C"], expanded: false)
]
```

As soon I try to apply it my program crashes:

> Cannot use instance member 'movies1' within property initializer,
>   property initializers run before 'self' is available

More info that might be helpful:

```
struct ExpandTVSection {
    var genre: String!
    var movies: [String]!
    var expanded: Bool!

    init(genre: String, movies: [String], expanded: Bool) {
        self.genre = genre
        self.movies = movies
        self.expanded = expanded
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift doesn't allow you to use properties (`movies1`) in initialization expression for another property (`sections`). Instead you can initialize your properties in an initializer (after calling a superclass initializer) or in your case just do:

```
ExpandTVSection(genre: "genre1", movies: [], expanded: false)
```

instead of

```
ExpandTVSection(genre: "genre1", movies: movies1, expanded: false)
```

Since your `movies1` is initialized with an empty array.

Comment: i solved it adding those lines 

(`self.sections.append(ExpandTVSection(genre: "genre1", movies: self.movies1, expanded: false))`)
(`self.moviesTableView.reloadData()`)